# How to Sendkeys on an element with aria-hidden=“true” using Selenium in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have code as below

[part one code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciD1g.png)

[part two code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW9Fl.png)

i try code

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='idms-input-labelledby-1601454890596-1']")).SendKeys("");
```

But I discovered that there is a mistake because the id changes every time

very thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id is really kept changing but you have to find what remains the same...

Your answer is probably:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-element']/input[contains(@class,'generic-input-field   form-textbox form-textbox-text')]")).SendKeys("urfirstname");
```

I tried this and it works.

Comment: thanks  , i try your code but show this massege error "element not interactable"

Comment: you can see this link page 
https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create

Comment: i try 

string str = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='firstNameInput']")).GetAttribute("value")    

output => {firstName}

Comment: Yes so this means that you manage to locate the element with my code and now you have another problem. But your main problem is now solved so you can add a check to my answer so people know it is solved and i will try to fix the other problem as well ;)

Comment: edited my answer and tested on local machine it is working...

Comment: sorry , i tested now but show msg no such element to locate element

Comment: change the xpath to this : //div[@class='form-element']/input

Comment: you can help me to lastname and birthday

Answer (score 0):

You could grab them all and send keys by accessing their indexes.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
List<WebElement> elements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//idms-error-wrapper/div/div/input")));
elements.get(0).SendKeys("");
```

Comment: Sorry , Get the same problem as the previous one

Comment: this code is worked driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-element']/input")).SendKeys("Firstname");
  but if go to textlastname not found element